# How can I easily change the text on a page using zend framework and php

Tags: php, zend-framework

What I am looking for is something where I can easily change the text on a page. I want to set it to a default value and if something is present for a specific page to change it

So it would say something like:

I like stackoverflow

But if the value of website was "reddit" it would instead say

I like reddit

So stackoverlflow would be the default, reddit would be something that is set to overwrite it.

edit:added comment

Comment: We were using language files before.  However, I would prefer something better than that.

Comment: How are you determining when to override the default message? Through a GET or POST variable? From a referring URL? A database value? An included file?

Comment: I'd suggest: "go and learn php" than "go and learn the manual page of Zend_View" :)

Comment: I am going to find out via the url.  I understand PHP but don't understand Zend very well.  Right now what we have is something like the following (not real code, just a real fast example)

if(fileexists($file_named_after_id_of_event)
{
   Get the variables in it
}
else
{
  Get Standard Variables
}

So then in the regular file I wouldn't have to look at anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenario I: Domain Name based data handling
If you want to work on the basis of domain, then in Zend Framework you can work with customize routers.

Scenario II: GET/POST based input handling
Otherwise if you want to display on the basis of GET or POST input you can place something default value as 
$myDynamicVar = $this->getRequest()->getParam('some_key', 'default-value');

Scenario III: subdomain based input handling
Again you will need to have your custom router for the purpose, in addition to having support of wildcard subdomain names with your hosting provider

Comment: okay,  I think Scenario #2 is real close.  I would have a file with all of the normal wording entered, however for an event that had different language I would want to store that into the DB.  What would be the best way to do it so I could just do something like $this->variableName; and it would automatically look based on eid if there was a replacement and if not it would give me the regular value.

Comment: Some more description to your problem could help pointing out the solution easier.

However I believe that you simply want to display (for instance) 'Bonjour', if and only if its replacement is _NOT_ present in the database. From this perspective;

<?php
$var = "Bonjour";
$dbValue = $db->queryResult("...where text='bonjour'");
if (!empty($dbValue)) {
$var = $dbValue;
}

Answer (score 0):

In a definitions file:

```
<?php 
/* site.php
 * customize this file 
 */
class Site 
{
    static public $name = "stackoverflow"; 
}
?>
```

In your page file:

```
<?php
/* page.php */
include_once 'site.php';
echo "I like {Site::$name}";    
?>
```